# Understanding SQL Server Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) master keys

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I have a lack of understanding regarding a particular area of TDE within Microsoft SQL Server (in my case, SQL Server 2016). Specifically what certificates/keys are required to restore an encrypted database on another server.

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-2016) highlight the encryption hierarchy, running from service master key, database master key, certificate and database encryption key. It highlights the necessity of creating backups of the certificate to prevent data loss. It doesn't really mention anything of backing up anything above the certificate in the hierarchy.

However a [Redgate article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-development/encrypting-sql-server-transparent-data-encryption-tde/) describes backing up the service master key and database master key in addition to the certificate.

In practice I am able to restore an encrypted database on another server using only the saved certificate/private key.. so what am I missing? If the certificate is protected by a master key that is not available, how does it work? Is that part of the encryption 'internal-only' - if so is there any instance where I would need to restore the service master key or database master key from a backup? I suppose keeping a backup of those wouldn't hurt anyway?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've successfully restored a TDE-encrypted database onto a server that has only the certificate that was used for TDE. Said another way, the destination server had *neither* matching a matching database master key (DMK) on the master database *nor* a matching service master key (SMK). So long as the DMK for the master database is encrypted with the SMK on the target and the TDE certificate's private key is loaded into master and encrypted with that DMK, you should be good to go.

But! For something like this, you shouldn't take my (a random guy on the internet) word for it. This fundamentally affects your ability to restore your database. Restore-ability is Job One™ for a DBA, you should try it and convince yourself that not only what I'm saying is true but also that *you* can do it.

Also, as part of that restore plan, take that certificate (along with its private key), back it up to disconnected media, and put it somewhere for safe keeping (I like to give it to the legal department).

Comment: Upped for the good advice (test and be sure). IMHO TDE is all rather convoluted and not intuitive (at least for someone that does this rarely).